# JQuery - Add two DOM elements in a <ul> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to add two elements in a `ul` (called `menu`) element:

`$('#menu').append($('<li>')).append($('<a>'), {id: 'page3', href:'#', text:'page3'});`

I am missing the link, if I create the `<li>`and `<a>`. Any ideas?

Comment: You have the values for an object?

Comment: why not combine it in one append like `<li><a></a></li>`

Comment: I don't like to append html code to create dom elements. I thought It can better readable if I create the elements one by one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*«I thought It can better readable if I create the elements one by one....»*

Here is one by one method... Making it clearer to re-read code.

```js
// Your object
var myobject = {id: 'page3', href:'#', text:'page3'};

// Create the li
var list_item = $("<li>");

// Create the anchor and use the object data to set the attribute and text
var anchor = $("<a>")
               .attr("id",myobject.id)
               .attr("href",myobject.href)
               .text(myobject.text);

// Append the anchor to the li
list_item.append(anchor);

// Append the li to the menu
$('#menu').append(list_item);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

That *«one by one»* method may be clearer for you to re-read your code...
But it uses many methods calls which can be reduced.

- **2** times `.append()`
- **2** times `.attr()`
- **1** time `.text()`

So that won't be the best thing to do when you'll be considering performance.
At this point, you should be able to read the *one liner* code.

The shortest way to do it, from an object, would be by using string concatenation:

```js
// Your object
var myobject = {id: 'page3', href:'#', text:'page3'};

// Append the li to the menu
$('#menu').append($('<li><a href="'+myobject.href+'" id="'+myobject.id+'">'+myobject.text+'</a></li>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

See? That is **1** `.append()` call only.
;)

Comment: Thanks for the accept... I edited with a more performant way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

The elements of `<ul>` are supposed to be `<li>` elements, you shouldn't have `<a>` appended directly to it. The `<a>` should be appended to the `<li>`.

Also, the object with the properties of the `<a>` should be the second argument to that call to `$()`, not a separate argument to `.append()`.

```js
$('#menu').append($('<li>').append($('<a>', {id: 'page3', href:'#', text:'page3'})));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```